# Why selenium crashes when I set google chrome profile?

Tags: python, selenium

So thats my code, I want to open chrome with my default profile information in selenium. but its doesn't load and crashes when I click on profile icon in chrome

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Desktop/supbot/chromedriver', options=options, service_log_path="/tmp/log")
driver.get('google.com')
```

Comment: im using add_experimental_option with exclude switches, maybe thats a reason?

Answer (score 0):

You should use full path to the driver file like:

```
C:\pathtodriver\chromedriver.exe
```

Also, avoid using `Capabilities`, try this approach:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get('google.com')
```

Comment: thats don't work